# Given 3 Vertices of a Tetrahedron, Find the 4th

Tags: geometry, triangles, spherical-geometry, spherical-coordinates, polygons

A regular tetrahedron is circumscribed by the Earth (assume spherical). You are given 3 of the 4 vertices (as latitude and longitude in decimal format), and asked to find the 4th. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: can they be represented by vectors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372556/given-three-points-on-a-tetrahedron-find-the-4th maybe this will help you

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130518024836AAXTKhS

Comment: Is it a *regular* tetrahedron? Do you know the sphere? If the answer to both is yes, I'd take the center of the known face, find the line perpendicular to it, then intersect that with the sphere.